# Laravel where dates by specific format

Tags: php, laravel, date, eloquent

In DB Col Name('publish') varchar format d/m/Y  for Example  30/1/2020
when try to get dates less than 30/1/2020 get any date less than days

> for example

```
->where('publish','<','30/01/2020')
```

`29/2/2020`  less than `30/1/2020` so i get any date under 30 by day not month or year

Comment: What is the column type of `publish`?

Comment: varchar (string)

Comment: make your string date as carbon object as `Carbon::parse('30/01/2020')` then you can compare it as date easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your Eloquent model define an accessor to retrive `publish` as carbon object

```
public function getPublishAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

now on your controller compare both date as below

```
->where('publish','<',Carbon::parse('30/01/2020'))
```

hope it helps!

Comment: you can't parse Carbon::parse('30/01/2020')  normal format for parse is m/d/Y

Comment: `Carbon::parse('30/01/2020')` will convert the date as 'Y/m/d' format, but it will work fine for condition as both in date instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB::raw` and `str_to_date` for the same:

```
 ->where(DB::raw('str_to_date(publish, "%d/%m/%Y")'),'<','30/01/2020' )
```

`str_to_date` will convert your varchar field to datetime field.

[MySQL -> Date and Time Functions-> STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: your Query look like tis good but not working   giv thisSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'str_to_date' (SQL: select * from `store_permissions` where `target_id` = 33 and DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(publish), "%d/%m/%Y") < 12/01/2020 and `store_permissions`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Actually str_to_date takes 2 parameters and I by mistake I passed only 1. Try now